# How can I prevent adding the same value (With another key) into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I need to fill a dictionary with pairs key-value given by the next code:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    d = {}
    Ri = Vector([#SomeCoordinates])

    for k in range(1,n+1):
        Rk = Vector([#SomeCoordinates])

        if i != k:
            d['R'+str(i)+str(k)] = (Rk-Ri).mod  # Distance between Ri and Rk
        else:
            None

""" Since  (Rk-Ri).mod  gives me the distance between two points (i and k),     
it's meaningless to calc the distance if i == k. """
```

Here's the problem:

'Rik'  represents the same distance as 'Rki' and I don't want to add a distance twice.

Then, I tried with this code:

```
        if i != k and ( ('R'+str(i)+str(k)) and ('R'+str(k)+str(i)) ) not in d:
            d['R'+str(i)+str(k)] = (Rk-Ri).mod
        else:
            None
```

but the problem is still there.

When I "print d" I get R12 but also R21 (And the same with every pair of numbers " i k ").

What can I do?

Comment: Use can use frozenset as a key, it's unordered so frozenset({1, 2}) and frozenset({2, 1}) have the same hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    Ri = Vector([#SomeCoordinates]).
    for k in range(i + 1, n + 1):
        Rk = Vector([#SomeCoordinates])
        d[i, k] = d[k, i] = (Rk - Ri).mod
```

This way we ensure we'll take only a pair (by enforcing `k > i`) and then we can assign to the dictionary the distance for both `(i, k)` and `(k, i)`.

I used `d[i, k]` instead of `d['R' + str(i) + str(k)]` because the latter has the following disadvantage: We can't infer for example, if `d['R123']` refers to `(12, 3)` or `(1, 23)`.

Also, I moved dictionary initialisation (`d = {}`) outside both loops, because it's initialised for each `i`.

Answer (score 2):

If I undertand you correctly, you are looking for all the combinations of two elements. You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to autoamtically generate all such combinations with no duplicates.

```
d = {}
for i, k in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), 2):
    Ri = Vector([SomeCoordinates])
    Rk = Vector([SomeCoordinates])
    d['R'+str(i)+str(k)] = (Rk-Ri).mod
```

You could even make it a dict comprehension (although it may be a bit long):

```
d = {'R'+str(i)+str(k)] : (Vector([SomeCoordinates]) - Vector([SomeCoordinates])).mod 
     for i, k in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), 2)}
```

Or, to do the (possibly expensive) calculation of `Vector([SomeCoordinates])` just once for each value of `i` or `k`, try this (thanks to *JuniorCompressor* for pointing this out):

```
R = {i: Vector([SomeCoordinates]) for i in range(1, n+1)}
d = {(i, k): (R[i] - R[k]).mod for i, k in itertools.combinations(range(1, n+1), 2)}
```

Also, as others have noted, `'R'+str(i)+str(k)` is not a good key, as it will be impossible to distinguish between e.g. `(1,23)` and `(12,3)`, as both end up as `'R123'`. I suggest you just use the tuple `(i,k)` instead.

Comment: I thought this, but it may be very slow to initialize `Ri` over and over again

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Hm, good point, that _might_ be an issue... but maybe it's not.

Comment: What about:  `R = [Vector([#SomeCoordinates]) for i in range(n)]`
   `d = {(i, k): (R[i] - R[k]).mod for i, k in combinations(range(n), 2)}`

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Good idea. Added this to my answer.

Comment: Saw that...Coolest answer so far

Answer (score 0):

You might always put the smaller value first so that a previous entry is automatically overwritten:

```
if i != k:
    key = str(i) + "," + str(k) if i < k else str(k) + "," + str(i)
    d['R'+key] = (Rk-Ri).mod
```

(I assume that your script only needs the distance values, not information from the current keys.)